# If value of POST = "0" then $Vid = "$row['video']

Tags: if-statement, post, row, isset

```
 if ($_POST['video'] == '0 lets say') {the $vid=$row['video']}

how would i define this correctly
```

so that i can set the value of video in the initial post form 
as 0 lets say or any other number, 
and on recieving the value through If isset$post 
- if the value actually equals "0 lets say" 
then $vid can = $row['video']

```
Basically
```

how can this be achieved,... thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_POST['video'] == '0') {
$videoID = $vid;
} else {
    $videoID = $videoID;
}
```

sorry i should of looked around 1st. but thanks for any interest...